# get individual data with response.data in angularjs. According to the code, the vm.userRole is undefined

Tags: node.js, angularjs, mongodb, express

```
  vm.trialLogin =function(){
        vm.credentials.userRole = "";
         authentication
           .userRole(vm.credentials.email)
           .then(function successCallback(response){
            // var data = response.data;
            // console.log("login data ", response.data);
             //vm.data = {loginData: data};
             vm.userRole = response.data.userRole;
             vm.email = response.data.email;
             console.log("the retrieved userrole is", vm.userRole);
           }
           ,function errorCallback(response) {
            vm.formError = "No such data";
            console.log(response);
           });

           
      }
```

Comment: How about `console.log("login data ", response.data);` output?

Comment: Indenting your code with 4 spaces per level will help it be readable.

Comment: using response.data gets the whole array object, how do i retrieve individual values from the array object and assign it to $scope or any other variable

Comment: Access array item first, then get the property.

Comment: i am accessing the array item using specific email. how do i assign values to scope  related to this email for instance userRole, phonenumber etc

Comment: [{…}]
0:
email: "justicemwanzamj@gmail.com"
hash: "nR9WQA7mm3rYPuKKqCdmemghfweDpWm5bFre2BTLZ8CCf5PWFz0znABUgleig0RwzvHbwvPoMmg4dMkCJHS2BQ=="
name: "mtende"
phonenumber: "0884253633"
salt: "ecb7d69458a44c4ce6041f1aadf29976"
userRole: "Farmer"
__v: 0
_id: "617e3a2d3561824e7500c6e6"
[[Prototype]]: Object
length: 1
[[Prototype]]: Array(0) ...how can i access the specific values like userRole in that using response

Comment: Rather than paste long bits of unformatted content into comments, format the output so its legible and put it in your question, along with a specific question about exacly what you are trying to achieve and what part is confusing you.